# Telerik upgrade's affected styling of certain controls

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik, styling

We've recently upgraded our Telerik library to Q3 2011, and it seems to have messed up the styling of some controls. The RadUpload for example is now of Width 80px (despite the fact I'm setting it at 500px). It's being rendered as...

```
<span class="ruFileWrap ruStyled" style="width: 80px;" jQuery171041561896132524767="11">
    <input class="ruFileInput" id="ctl00_MainContent_Edit1_RadUpload1file0" submitName="ctl00_MainContent_Edit1_RadUpload1file0" type="file" size="23" unselectable="on" _events="[object Object]"/>
    <label style="display: none;" for="ctl00_MainContent_Edit1_RadUpload1file0">
    <input class="ruFakeInput" id="ctl00_MainContent_Edit1_RadUpload1TextBox0" type="text" size="22"/>
    <label style="display: none;" for="ctl00_MainContent_Edit1_RadUpload1TextBox0">
    <input class="ruButton ruBrowse" type="button" value="Select"/>
```

From the following asp .net...

```
        <telerik:RadUpload MaxFileSize="512000" OverwriteExistingFiles="true" ControlObjectsVisibility="None"
          runat="server" ID="RadUpload1" OnValidatingFile="uploadMedia_ValidatingFile"
          OnClientFileSelected="uploadMedia_FileSelected" Width="500px" />
```

Does anyone have any idea where the styling is defined for these controls? Where the 80px has came from? Or how I can at least somehow 'override' this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you post your aspx content rather than the rendered html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-appearance-file-input-appearance.html you have 2 different parameters you can set:

**InputSize** - set this property to an integer value to increase the width of all file input elements.

**Width** - set this property in pixels to increase the width of the whole RadUpload area containing all elements such as buttons, file input fields, etc.

```
<telerik:radupload id="Radupload1" runat="server" enablefileinputskinning="true"
    inputsize="50" width="475px" skin="Web20"></telerik:radupload>
```